# Can I host a Microsoft Access database in Office365?

Tags: office-365, access-services

Is there an Office365 plan that allows me to upload a Microsoft Access database into Access Services?  I cannot see that any of the plans support this, but I'd be surprised there truly is not a way.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/compare-plans.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is. See the Office 365 page on [Access Services](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/move-your-data-to-access-and-office-365-HA102610172.aspx) and this [MSDN Lab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Office365TrainingCourse_Lab_5_2).
I am pretty sure they are available in the E3 and E4 plans.
A quote from the  Office 365 Page:

> Do you have valuable data that is stored in an old, unsupported
>   database, where it’s hard to query or maintain? By moving your data to
>   Microsoft Access 2010, and then publishing the database to Access
>   Services on Office 365, you can make your data accessible to all of
>   your colleagues wherever they are. Perhaps more importantly, your
>   database will be better able to grow as your needs change.

Comment: You can also view this TechNet article which covers the plans as well. http://blogs.technet.com/b/lystavlen/archive/2011/09/23/office-365-comparing-p-and-e-plans.aspx

Comment: Many thanks.  I looked and looked, then googled and binged, but couldn't find this information.

Comment: Access services has now been deprecated in Office 365: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Office-Retirement-Blog/Updating-the-Access-Services-in-SharePoint-Roadmap/ba-p/57148?utm_content=buffer08b37&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Answer (score 2):

Access Services is supported in E3 and E4 - as well as the P1 plan. In other words, yes.

Comment: Do other users need an E3 or E4 plan to use the Access Database?  Or do you just need the license to upload/maintain it?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is available yet, however I believe I saw it on a roadmap in some presentation somewhere. They are working on moving all of the same features into the online version and have made a lot of great improvements since it was released. I would expect it would happen this year. If I could log into my 365 account from my current location I could confirm that it does not work right now. Ill give it a shot this evening and let you know. I am using the E3 Plan.